# Clacissisme ou classicisme

Tags: orthographe

Ma prof de français dit qu’il faut écrire « clacissisme », pourtant, s’il l’on cherche sur Google, il nous propose de l'écrire « classicisme ».

Mais on trouve tout de même des résultats avec la première orthographe : 11 800 résultats environ (contre 10 millions avec la deuxième).

Pour moi, la deuxième orthographe semble également plus logique, s’apparentant à « classique ».

Comment faut-il écrire ce mot ? Il y a t-il des différences de sens entre les deux orthographes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La version correcte est bien ***classicisme*** dont l'Étymologie est la suivante:

> Mot dérivé de classique avec le suffixe -isme.
>       (1817) Avec le sens de « caractère des œuvres littéraires qui se réfèrent à l’art antique » ; (1875) avec celui de « caractère de ce qui est harmonieux, équilibré ». Du latin classicus « de première classe », le français a retenu l′idée de qualité, d′excellence. Au XVIIe siècle, ce terme désigne les auteurs antiques, (latins particulièrement), dignes d′être enseignés dans les écoles.
>    Source: [Wikitionaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/classicisme)

Le mot *« clacissisme »* n'existe pas et n'est donc pas utilisé en Français, c'est une très bonne chose d'avoir remis en question les paroles de votre professeur ainsi que d'avoir fait la démarche de vous renseigner par vous même. Je vous en félicite.

Answer (score 0):

Clacissisme est un mot occitan selon ce dictionnaire https://fr.glosbe.com/oc/fr/clacissisme signifiant bien sûr classicisme. Cependant je me demande comment la professeure s'est trompée.